# ROR Scaffold Destroy redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, destroy

I actually built a 'Offer' scaffold referenced to user (devise) and product. I can add an offer on the specific product page. However, I realise when I try to delete an offer, it is by default redirected to products_url. How can I redirect it back to the specific product page? When I create the comment, it does redirect_to the specific product page. Delete doesnt do so.
I have tried using

Original code

```
class OffersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_offer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
 @offers = Offer.all
 end

def show
end

def new
 @offer = Offer.new
 end

 # GET /offers/1/edit
 def edit
 end

 # POST /offers
 # POST /offers.json
 def create
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@offer = @product.offers.new(offer_params)
@offer.user = current_user

respond_to do |format|
  if @offer.save
    format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Offer was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @offer }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @offer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
 end

 # PATCH/PUT /offers/1
 # PATCH/PUT /offers/1.json
 def update
   respond_to do |format|
     if @offer.update(offer_params)
       format.html { redirect_to @offer, notice: 'Offer was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @offer }
     else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @offer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
  end

     # DELETE /offers/1
  # DELETE /offers/1.json
   def destroy
   @offer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to product_url, notice: 'Offer was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
   end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
   def set_offer
    @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
    end

     # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def offer_params
      params.require(:offer).permit(:product_id, :priceOffer, :user_id)
   end
 end
```

I tried to modify

```
def destroy
@offer.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Offer was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
```

It actually showed my error. The 26 is actually offer_id. It should actually redirect to http://localhost:3000/products/18 . It showed me the extracted source as below.

```
Couldn't find Product with 'id'=26
def set_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I've understood the question but I think you just need to pass the product's id as an additional parameter, something like:

```
= link_to 'destroy', offer_path(@offer, product_id: @product.id), method: :delete
```

and then in your controller use

```
redirect_to product_path(params[:product_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in destroy method.

Product =@offer.product

redirect_to :product

@product you have used is not set. So we need to set product_id here.
That's why we took product id from offer variable through relation

Answer (score 0):

what you did in set_product just use params[:id] to find product, but the params[:id] is refer to the offer_id when you call destroy, that's why you get the RecordNotFoundError. I think you can write this.

```
def set_product
  # maybe you should judge whether @product is nil or not
  @product = @offer.product
end
```